# How to make unit test assertions in a unit testing framework agnostic manner

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, mstest, xunit

I'm presently working with a home spun unit testing helper package that is consumed by several internal projects. Up until recently this solution has been working well for us, and helps us follow the DRY principal for common testing helper methods. Unfortunately, this project is currently tied to nUniut, and we've just inherited some xUnit test projects that could benefit from this helper. This becomes a problem as each testing framework seems to manage assertions and watches for different thrown exceptions to indicate test failure.

I was hoping that it would simply be a matter of inheriting from a base exception class and most unit test frameworks would just catch and handle it as a failed (or passed) assertion appropriately. This however seems not to be the case.

Is there a proper way to Assert / throw Assertion exceptions without a direct unit test framework dependency that may can be consumed by the appropriate test runner? Or does a custom adapter have to be created for each unit test framework in order for my helper classes to be free from such a direct dependency of the test projects unit testing framework?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Unless I misunderstand its usage the various Debug.Assert methods are only applicable in a debug environment, and are different from unit test assertions.

Comment: any unit test assertion can be converted into boolean

Comment: I don't disagree with that, however Debug.Assert (and Trace.Assert) statements are not unit test assertions. They are not caught by xUnit or nUnit test runners (I've not verified with MSTest) Their usage is for diagnostics, not unit testing.

Comment: Knowing the internals of NUnit, I think you are going to need to create some sort of exception provider/factory for each supported test framework. NUnit only treats NUnit exceptions as test failures, any other exception is treated as unexpected and causes the test to be in error.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create an interface and implement it in a separate adapter per framework. The resulting feature set would be the lowest common denominator of all the frameworks you support.

I imagine that this would only be satisfying to folks who are real novices. It would mean you couldn't take advantage of advanced productivity-enhancing features, which exist in both NUnit and xUnit in incompatible form.

You have to ask yourself if uniformity is really that valuable.